# Not able to connect to Snowflake from EMR Cluster using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to Snowflake from EMR cluster using pyspark.

I am using these two jars  in spark-submit.

- snowflake-jdbc-3.5.2.jar
- spark-snowflake_2.11-2.7.0-spark_2.4.jar

But it failing with connect time out error. 
I have correct proxy configured for the EMR cluster. From the same EC2 (EMR Master)
 I am able to connect to Snowflake using `snowsql` and python connector.

I am not sure why it is getting timed out for pyspark.

Comment: can you share code snippet you are following ? some times due to proxy issues it may not connect. like   http_proxy , https_proxy , HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY no_proxy settings needs to be used in such cases

Comment: SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
sfOptions = {"sfURL": "XXX",
             "sfAccount": "XX",
             "sfUser": "XX",
             "sfPassword": "xx",
             "sfDatabase": "xx",
             "sfSchema": "xx",
             "sfWarehouse": "xx"}
query = "select * from testdb.test1.t1"
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query",  query).load()

Comment: I am able to connect to snowflake using snowsql  and python connector from the same ec2 instance.

Comment: have you checked co proxy as mentioned above ? remaining all looks good also you need to use biz_pstage_work as schema for sprak to connect to sf

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace here ? Below were my commands when I tried running thru EMR shell.(some older versions of jar )



spark-submit --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4 SparkConnPython.py



pyspark --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use our SnowCD tool to check the connectivity diagnostics. This is related to network issues.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

Below were my commands when I tried running through EMR shell.

pyspark --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.6.27,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.4.14-spark_2.4

spark-submit --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4 SparkConnPythonWithCert.py

Spark-shell --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.8.0,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.4.14-spark_2.4